# add CSS with array of variables in head - Wordpress - PHP

Tags: php, css, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I'm trying to return css build with multiple variables in my Wordpress website, its kind of working but it's only returning the first array. If i echo instead of return inside the foreach it shows the code correctly but outside the correct location.

Sorry for the bad code and possible definitions about php. I have only just started to learn php.

**The code**

```
 function child_custom_color_css4() {
    function child_custom_color_css2() {

        

        function test_loop_1_beta() {
            $boo = 'soortverhaal0 ';
            $foo = 'soortverhaal1 ';
            return array($boo, $foo);
        }

        $loops = test_loop_1_beta();

        
        
        global $nectar_options;

        $Styled=array();
            foreach ($loops as $loop) {
                
                return '
            
                #test-loop.'. $loop .' {
                background-color: '.esc_attr($nectar_options["accent-color"]).' !important;
                }
                
                ';

        }
        return implode($Styled);
        

    }

    $get_arrays = child_custom_color_css2();
    
    wp_add_inline_style( 'main-styles', $get_arrays);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','child_custom_color_css4', 20); '''
```

**Output:**

```
<style id="main-styles-inline-css" type="text/css">

        
            #test-loop.soortverhaal0  {
            background-color: #f04e23 !important;
            }
            
</style>
```

**Edit: what need:**

```
<style id="main-styles-inline-css" type="text/css">

            #test-loop.soortverhaal0  {
            background-color: #f04e23 !important;
            }

            #test-loop.soortverhaal1  {
            background-color: #f04e23 !important;
            }
            
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do something like that:

```
function child_custom_color_css4() {
    function child_custom_color_css2() {

        $loops = [
          'soortverhaal0 ',
          'soortverhaal0 ',
        ];

        global $nectar_options;

        $styled = [];
        
        foreach ($loops as $loop) {
          $styled[] = '#test-loop.' . $loop . ' { background-color: ' . esc_attr( $nectar_options['accent-color'] ) . ' !important; }';
        };

        return implode("\n",$styled);
        
    }

    $get_arrays = child_custom_color_css2();
    
    wp_add_inline_style( 'main-styles', $get_arrays);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','child_custom_color_css4', 20);
```

I do an array push to acumulate each loop into $style array.

I think you would need to define other separator for the implode function like:

```
return implode("\n",$styled)
```

Comment: Looks promising thank you, but the end `}`of the functions are not matching. I thought the `}`  above the `return implode("\n",$styled);` needs to go, but removing this gives an empty result. The '`<style>` is complete empty. Not getting error's

Comment: yes, sorry that `}` should be included after the !mportant, closing the style scope. I edited the code, please check now.

Comment: Unfortunately I now get no code at all, not even error

Comment: Ey man, sorry… i didn’t get a chance to test this code…but I’m seeing other issue in my code… the array is called $styled and we are pushing the data into an array with other name ($styleArray)…soo I edited the code again replacing $styledArray by $styled. Please check again, hope it works

Comment: Thanks this is it! (one little thing you changed the loops = with 2 of the same arrays.) I renamed some of the functions to make it more readable in english etc. Is there a way in this platform i can send you the code?

Thanks for helping me out and understanding php a lot more!

Comment: i have edited your answer to make it more readable and understandable for the community. Edit only needs to be approved by trusted community members.

Thank you very much for the help, any improvements are very welcome!